# Why is the title content submitted as value to an input field

Tags: html, input, title

I have the problem, that the title-element seems to get posted as the input-elements value if the element is left empty (which is allowed).

Why is this and how can I simply add a tooltip to the input field which does not compromise the value of the input field?

Used browsers: Firefox 52, Chromium

```html
<input id="my_text_input" type="text" title="Type in some (specific) text" /> <label>Text</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I found the mistake. This is an old legacy-project and it had some JavaScript quirks, for instance:

- when an input-field has a "title" attribute, set value=title
- when someone clicks into the element, set value=""

this broke my code and brought this strange behaviour